# making an auto layout of UIimageView and textview inside scrollview for iOS 10.2 in xcode8

Tags: ios, xcode8, ios-autolayout

I am making a note taking app in xcode8 for iOS 10.2. The note is consist of a textfield, textview and imageview. I am adding textview and imageview in separate scrollviews (to provide the facility of zooming and adjusting image). Then I have added both scroll views in a stackview to ensure that imageview and textview stands side by side in a landscape mode. To do that, I have added variation to axis property of stackview( width=any, height= compact and Gamut=any, and set that to the horizontal, as shown in right corner of screenshot [to see view hierarchy without any constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E65En.png)).
I have tried many constraints but, every time it fails to adopt. Let's take an example, I am adjusting size of the scrollviews on the size of content(by setting top,bottom,leading and trailing constraint), the stack view is adjusted to the main view. Now, the only thing that needs to be adjusted is text view and imageview with respect of stack view. But, here is the tricky part If I include a fixed trailing constraint of text view to the stack view; it will work in portrait mode.As soon I turn into landscape mode that constraint will not work(the trailing constraint which have 0 distance from stackview) because the edge will be side to the imageview not to the stackview(because I am putting image and text side by side as explained above) which will make textview larger than required, same goes for imageview's leading constraint to the stack view and vertical distance constraint betweem image view and textview.I think the root of the problem is I have made a variation to the axis of a stack view (in order to get text and image side by side in landscape mode) but, that was necessary part.Can anyone have solution for this? Do you think there can be other problem? Should I choose Intrinsic Size of scrollviews to placeholder option or let it be system default?

Thank you.

Comment: Simplify your question.. It has been 14 hours and there's no answers. There's a reason for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I hope I understand the question and I will try to walk you through what I understand you hope to accomplish.  I preface this by saying I just started using UIStackView because of backwards compatibility.

Note.  To get the magic of ScrollView with AutoLayout I almost always embed them in another UIView.  There are reasons to not but in this case you will see how valuable this is to AutoLayout.

Step 1) Drag your UIStackView and add Top,Bottom,Leading, and Trailing.  Now add 2 UIViews and set the UIStackView to Fill Equally.  It will now look like the image(Background colors to check your work).[image: StackViewStep1]

Step 2) Now add a UIScrollView to each of these UIViews.  Add Leading,Trailing,Top,and Bottom on each of these.

Step 3) Add a UITextView and UIImageView to the ScrollViews respectively.  Now Autolayout is mad at us :( but we will fix that.

Step 4) Drag from the UIImageView to the View that is holding the UIScrollView(First Set of Views we added).  See image

[image: Step4]

-Choose the option to add Equal Widths. See Image
[image: EqualWidths]

Repeat the same step but add Equal Heights.  Now add Top, Bottom, Leading, and Trailing to the ScrollView.

Step 5) Repeat exact Step 4 with UITextView

Your final view hierarchy should look like this.
[image: Final]

Now you can rotate your UIStackView and do what you want I think.
[image: StackVertical]

And Horizontal
[image: Horizontal]

Side by Side Preview
[image: SideBySide]

I did add a <= 0.1 equal heights multiplier on the textfield at the top but I don't know if that was necessary.

Enjoy.

Comment: Thanks for help. Though I did it using using similar method, I used stack views to embed each item and then grouped them again using stack views.

Comment: Plus I don't call what you describe in the last comment at all similar to what is above in my answer.

Comment: Yeah, I should have given you more than one upvote as you understood that messy question in first place. lol. I did give you an upvote it is recorded but not shown publically as my rating are less than 15. Sorry for that :(

Comment: I don't think a rank is required.  I think you just click the checkmark below the up vote arrows.

Comment: oh sorry for that, Done!

Comment: thanks.  that way it will also be marked in the tags as answered as well